# SQLite, Content Resolver and Download Manager

Tags: sqlite, android-download-manager, resolver

Is it possible to use Download manager to download a file from the internet and save the details e.g. name, type, category on the SQLite db using content resolver? I have scenario where details are not saved on the database when back is pressed. When you leave the activity nothing is saved on the db. You have to stay on the activity to save the details on the db.

Comment: Are you committing the changes to the database?

Comment: yes...details are saved only when you stay on the activity. @RegularlyScheduledProgramming